# How to shim XmlAttribute using Microsoft Fakes in VS 2013

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I have the below code I am testing.

```
    public Loader(XmlAttributeCollection attributes)
    {

        if (attributes == (XmlAttributeCollection)null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("attributes");
        foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in attributes)
        {
            if (attribute.Name.Equals("name", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                name = attribute.Value;
            }
            else if (attribute.Name.Equals("type", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                loaderType = attribute.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                loaderAttributes.Add(attribute.Name, attribute.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Is that possible to shim the attribute/attributecollection so that I can return whichever the attribute object I want to return ?

For example I want to return two xmlattribute objects one with attribute name of "name" and another one as "type" and also their respective values .

What I meant is something like below shim statement where instead of returning null , can I return an xmlattribute object with name and value ?

```
            ShimXmlAttributeCollection.AllInstances.ItemOfGetInt32 = (x, y) =>
            {
                return null;
            };
```

Here is the sample xml I have.

```
<add name=\"console\" type=\"DefaultTraceLoader\" value=\"Error\"/>
```

Comment: You would have to fake the `GetEnumerator()` method. I don't have Fakes on this PC so I can't show you how.... but simply returning a `new XmlAttribute[] { your elements }.GetEnumerator()` should be enough.

Comment: It's a good suggestion. But GetEnumerator () method is not available in the StubXmlAttributeCollection or ShimXmlAttributeCollection.

Comment: @krishna Because it is defined in `XmlNamedNodeMap`... Try looking in `StubXmlNamedNodeMap`

Comment: Ok.I used it and it is available as ShimXmlNamedNodeMap.It also worked. But is it possible to pass my xml content directly in the ShimXmlNamedNodeMap while returning GetEnumerator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml("<add name=\"console\" type=\"DefaultTraceLoader\" value=\"Error\"/>");
var enumerator = xml.DocumentElement.Attributes.GetEnumerator();
```

BEFORE setting the `ShimXmlNamedNodeMap.AllInstances.GetEnumerator`.

```
ShimXmlNamedNodeMap.AllInstances.GetEnumerator = x =>
{
    return enumerator;
};
```

Comment: Is that not possible to stub this XmlDocument ? It would be great if it is possible to do so.

Comment: @krrishna What do you mean?

Comment: I was asked not to use XmlDocument directly instead I was asked to stub it. So is it possible ?

Comment: @krrishna I don't comprehend if you don't want to do the `XmlDocument`/`LoadXml` inside the unit test, or if you want to create an `XmlDocument` replacement that uses interfaces/virtual methods and that then can be stubbed or what